# What should be written in catkin_package?

Tags: ros, catkin-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, my name is Kaori Furuike.

I have a question about "10. Creating msg and srv" in beginner level tutorials. (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)
It tells us to make sure we export the message runtime dependency.

```
catkin_package(
  ...
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
  ...)
```

But there is no statement like "CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ..." in my catkin_package.
And when I run without such a statement, I got this error message.

```
"Unable to load msg [beginner_tutorials/Num]: Cannot locate message [Num]: unknown package [beginner_tutorials] on search path [{'rosconsole': ['/opt/ros/hydro/share/rosconsole/msg'], ..."
```

Would you tell me what is (or what shold be) written in catkin_package at beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt ?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194251/what-should-be-written-in-catkin_package-?/) by [Kaori Furuike](https://answers.ros.org/users/20398/kaori-furuike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-06**:
can you share your Cmakelist.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_package is documented in detail here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#catkin_package.28.29

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kaori Furuike](https://answers.ros.org/users/20398/kaori-furuike/) on 2014-10-14**:
Sorry for my late reply.
And thank you for your help. I finally succeeded to build this program.
catkin_package(
CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
}
was enough actually in this case. But I did not understand what catkin_package was, so the HP was very helpful.